# Using scrapy to scrape food aggregators like grubhub need it for some personal data science purpose

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to figure out a way to find the data out of the website using splash but have no result, I need your help on figuring out a way to do that!

**edit:**

*link:https://www.grubhub.com/search?location=10001*(link edited for brevity)
and similarly, this for different states based on ZIP code and data I need is the name of the restaurant and its menu and ratings for all possible or available data.

Comment: Use `requests` library to do that

Comment: pls provide link to the websites and what do you want to collect?

Comment: Why do you want to use scrapy? Why should you not simply use their API?

Comment: @Gregor I didn't found API for this site as such and others don't offer what I need !! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reverse-engineer their API but you might have to adjust it to your needs (and probably optimise it according to your needs):

We will have to get an `authentication bearer` in order to use their API. To get the token we will first need a `client_id`:

## libraries I am using

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
```

## get client_id

```
session = requests.Session()

static = 'https://www.grubhub.com/eat/static-content-unauth?contentOnly=1'
soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(static).text, 'html.parser')
client = re.findall("beta_[a-zA-Z0-9]+", soup.find('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'}).text)
# print(client)
```

## get authentication bearer

```
# define and add a proper header
headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
        'authorization': 'Bearer',
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
          }
session.headers.update(headers)

# straight from networking tools. Device ID appears to accept any 10-digit value
data = '{"brand":"GRUBHUB","client_id":"' + client[0] + '","device_id":1234567890,"scope":"anonymous"}'
resp = session.post('https://api-gtm.grubhub.com/auth', data=data)

# refresh = json.loads(resp.text)['session_handle']['refresh_token']
access = json.loads(resp.text)['session_handle']['access_token']

# update header with new token
session.headers.update({'authorization': 'Bearer ' + access})
```

## make your request

Here comes the part that is different from your request: their API uses a third-party service to get the longitude and latitude for a ZIP code (i.e. -73.99916077, 40.75368499) for your New York ZIP code). There might even be an option to change that: `location=POINT(-73.99916077%2040.75368499)` looks like it accepts other options, as well.

```
grub = session.get('https://api-gtm.grubhub.com/restaurants/search/search_listing?orderMethod=delivery&locationMode=DELIVERY&facetSet=umamiV2&pageSize=20&hideHateos=true&searchMetrics=true&location=POINT(-73.99916077%2040.75368499)&facet=promos%3Atrue&facet=open_now%3Atrue&variationId=promosSponsoredRandom&sortSetId=umamiv3&countOmittingTimes=true')
```

Comment: I just wanted you to know you rock and are a badass API reverse-engineer. 

Comment: Thanks to @Gregor, I packaged this as a library: https://github.com/jlumbroso/grubhub